# How to automatically update reference models in mongoose by editing/creating documents in the corresponding 'referenced' model?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have 3 models in my API , Patient, Doctor and Reviews. I have referenced the Reviews model in the Doctor model. The idea is that a patient is able to post a review and rating for a particular doctor using Review.create(). However, after the document is created, I would like the reviews property for that particular doctor along with the averageRating and totalRatings property to be updated simultaneously as well. I already achieved this using mongoose update operators but its really messy so i was wondering if there is a better and cleaner way to achieve the same result.

patient Model:

```
const PatientSchema = new Schema<patientType>({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'please provide a product name'],
        maxlength: 50,
        minlength: 3
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'please provide an email'], 
        match: [
            /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/,
            'Please provide a valid email',
          ],
          unique: true,
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'please provide a password'],
        minlength: 8
    },
    phone: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0 
    },
    photo: {
        type: String
    },
    role: {
        type: String,
    },
    gender: {
        type: String,
        enum: ["male", "female", "other"]
    },
    bloodtype: {
        type: String
    },
    appointments: [{
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Booking',
        required: true
    }]
})
```

The Doctor Model:

```
const DoctorSchema = new Schema<doctorType>({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'please provide a product name'],
        maxlength: 50,
        minlength: 3
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'please provide an email'], 
        match: [
            /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/,
            'Please provide a valid email',
          ],
          unique: true,
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'please provide a password'],
        minlength: 8
    },
    phone: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0 
    },
    photo: {
        type: String
    },
    role: {
        type: String,
    },
    ticketPrice: {
        type: Number,
        default: 1000,
        required: true
    },
    specialization: {
        type: String,
    },
    qualifications: {
        type: [Object],
    },
    experiences: {
        type: [Object]
    },
    bio: {
        type: String,
        minlength: 5,
    },
    about: {
        type: String,
        minlength: 4
    },
    reviews: [{ 
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: "Review",
        required: true,
        default: []
    }],
    averageRating: {
        type: Number,
        max: 5,
        min: 0,
        default: 0
    },
    totalRatings: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    isApproved: {
        type: String,
        enum: ["pending", "approved", "cancelled"],
        default: 'pending'
    },
    appointments: [{
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Booking',
        required: true
    }]
    
})
```

Review Model:

```
const ReviewSchema = new Schema<reviewType>({
    doctor: {
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Doctor",
    },
    patient: {
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User",
    },
    text: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'please add a review text'],
    },
    rating: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 5,
        default: 0,
    },
},{ timestamps: true });
```

create doctor ratings function:

```
const postDoctorReviews = async (req: MyUserRequest, res: Response) => {
    const {id: doctorId} = req.params
    const {patientId} = req.user

    const {text, rating} = req.body

    if(!text || !rating){
        throw new BadRequestError('Field cannot be empty')
    }

    const doctorReview = await Review.create({doctor: doctorId, patient: patientId, ...req.body})

    const reviews = await Review.find({doctor: doctorId}) as reviewType[]

    const doc = await Doctor.findById( doctorId ) as doctorType

    const ratingsSum = reviews.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue.rating,0);

    const aveRating = ratingsSum/(doc.totalRatings + 1)
    
    const doctor = await Doctor.findByIdAndUpdate(doctorId,
        {
           $push: {
                reviews: doctorReview._id
           },
           $inc: {
                totalRatings: 1
           },
           $set: {
                averageRating: Math.round(aveRating)
           }
        },
    {new:true});
    doctor?.save()
    
    res.status(StatusCodes.CREATED).json({doctorReview})  
}
```

As you can see in the function above, i have already achieved this, i was just wondering if anyone had a cleaner solution.